Snowflake - Replacing an Apostrophe
I'm calling a snowflake stored procedure in an SSRS reporting, and the report is breaking because one of the data field contains an apostrophe "'".
Example: Doctor's Office
I used a semi colon (;) delimiter, but it didn't work
AND CSG4 IN (SELECT Value FROM table(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(:vGroup4,'';''))) 

SSRS dataset parameter
Join(Parameters!Group4.Value,";")

I tried replacing the data using select into a #TempTbl
SELECT REPLACE(<field>,''''','''') as field


Hi - can you clarify where you are trying to fix this? Are you trying to change your SP so that it doesn’t return apostrophes (in which case can you update your question with the SP code, or a minimal version of it), or are you trying to fix it in SSRS, or are you doing something else?

sounds like what you are wanting todo is replace the token not split the data...

with example_data as (
    select * from values
    ('Doctor\'s Office'),
    ('Doctor'),
    ('Office')
)
SELECT column1 as input, 
    replace(column1, '''',';') as replaced_1,
    replace(column1, '\'',';') as replaced_2
FROM example_data 

I used two was to show how to put a single quote inside the single quoted string format the Snowflake uses.


That works in SMS, but i'm trying to make it work in Snowflake sql block code where the values are enclosed in double quoted. For example: Replace(FieldName,''old'',''new''), but i am having difficulty applying this method in replacing the apostrophe with a blank inside the block code (BEGIN .... END)

Now you needs to escape it all, thus ether every single quote is doubled, ' -> '' or escaped ' -> \'
